# How to store mui-datatable filter chip while page refresh

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, mui-datatable

I have added mui datatable in my application but whenever I refresh the page all the filter options are gone, Is there any way to store then so that if a user refresh the website, they will still get the filter chip value.

```
let th = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', ...]

<MyMUIDataTable
          style={{ width: 'max-content' }}
          data={data}
          columns={th}
          options={options}
      />
```

[image]

How can I store "Device Installed" status while page refresh?